Primaris Eliminator, Hyperfrag Round - What happens to new creatures?
If Player A plays Primaris Eliminator in their first main phase, and chooses Hyperfrag Round as the mode, targeting Player B, what happens if Player B creates new creatures later within Player A's turn?
A simply example of this happening would be with Flash, but in this case it was with Waste Not, and the question arose regarding whether the created 2/2s would die instantly because of Hyperfrag Round, or if they survived and were unaffected because they came in later.
I feel confident the answer is that they survive, but I'm open to being surprised. Could someone explain what happens and why?

Creatures that entered after Hyperfrag Round resolves will not be affected by it.
Hyperfrag Round is a continuous effect. It was created by an ability and affects creatures' characteristics, their power and toughness. That means the set of affected creatures is determined only once and does not change later.

611.2c If a continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability modifies the characteristics or changes the controller of any objects, the set of objects it affects is determined when that continuous effect begins. After that point, the set won’t change. (Note that this works differently than a continuous effect from a static ability.) [..]


Awesome, this is super useful. Thank you!
